# how to send an array of numbers from servlets to a javascript

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, networking

> actually i want a server to send a list of numbers to a client and want the client to run >the javascript on its machine and send the result to server and server will verify >whether it is correct or not. how can we do this???....plzzz help

```
//this is the servlet code

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})

public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {   
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        System.out.println("Received following data from client:");
        // System.out.println(request.getParameter("type"));

        if(request.getParameter("type").equals("first")) {
        String ip= request.getLocalAddr();
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 4, 56, 78};

        String str="";
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            str += arr[i]+"#";//creating a seperator

        System.out.println("The string to be sent is: "+str);
        out.println(str);//to check if client is sending right request
        }
        else if(request.getParameter("type").equals("second")) {
            System.out.println("hiii");
            out.println("Sum received from client is: "+request.getParameter("sum"));
        }
    }

}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

this is the jsp code

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script>

    var list=[];

    function myFun() {
        alert("fun called");
        var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var j=0;
        obj.open("POST", "NewServlet", true);
        obj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        obj.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(obj.readyState===4 && obj.status===200) {
                alert(obj.responseText);//alert("response received from server- "+obj.responseText);

                var str = obj.responseText;
                var arr = str.split("#");
                alert(arr);
                var j=0;
                for(var i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
                    j+=parseInt(arr[i]);
                }
                alert(j);
                myFun1(j);
        }            
        };
         obj.send("type=first");
        //obj.send("sum="+j);

    }


    function myFun1(j) {

        var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        obj.open("POST", "NewServlet", true);
        obj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        obj.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(obj.readyState===4 && obj.status===200) {
                alert("sum sent to server");
                }
            };


        obj.send("sum="+j+"&type=second");

    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>


    <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:myFun()" value="click here to get list of Numbers" />

    <!--
    <form method="post" action="NewServlet">
        <input type="text" name="text1"><input type="submit" name="sub">
    </form>
    -->
</body>
```

Comment: You need to write code to form.submit() in your javascript in order to return value back to the server. And I would not use servlet to write html content. Why dont you use jsp instead?

Comment: Look into using AJAX for your page and server to communicate.

Comment: i have used ajax to implement the same but in the code i m sending a string of numbers from servlet to jsp and then sending the sum to the servlet back ..but servlet is not able to recieve the sum variable

and i have updated the code for the same..plz check it out

Answer (score 0):

In your case using a servlet seams to be appropriate. As I see the only obstacle is getting your numbers down to the view as you already use AJAX. Doing so you just have to retrieve a Writer from the `response` parameter in your `processRequest` method. I would use JSON notation in the servlet: `[1, 2, 4, 56, 78]` You just append your array to the responses Writer and the client is receiving it from it's AJAX request.

When this string arrives in the client JavaScript will like it better because parsing can be done using `JSON.parse([1, 2, 4, 56, 78])`

This should be it...